# How to select values grouped by column if another column has multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get from a table those values in column1, that have some values in column2.

For example, I want to get A because it has "1,2,3". (Expected Output of select: A)

```
---
A|1
A|2
A|3
A|4
B|1
B|3
---
```

This is what I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE Col2 in (1,2,3) GROUP BY col1
```

I understand perfectly it won't work, since I am just putting the condition that column 2 must have one of those values, and then I group them by Col1, so It will take (A,1),(A,2),(A,3),(B,1),(B,2) -> group them by Col1 and give me (A) and (B)

I really have no clue how I could force it to have **ALL** the 3 values

Here is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e283b/2) to try it

**NOTE**

Please feel free to edit the post in order to make it more understandable, I have tried my best, but I know its not very well explained, specially the title

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING()` clause :

```
SELECT col1
WHERE Col2 in (1,2,3) 
GROUP BY col1
HAVING COUNT(col2) = 3
```

This will show only results that have 3 values , and since you filtered only for `1,2,3` , if there are 3, it those 3.

**Note** : If the values on col2 are not distinct , E.G. it's possible for this data to appear:

```
A | 1
A | 1
A | 2
```

Then add `DISTINCT` inside the parentheses of the count.

Comment: DISTINCT is (hopefully) redundant in this instance. Otherwise we're missing a PRIMARY KEY :-(

Comment: I'll have to agree, I removed it :) @Strawberry

Comment: Actually according to what OP wants, distinct is mandatory here otherwise all col1 values that has any combination of (1,2,3) as col2 will be displayed

Comment: Alright! that worked out perfectly! Thank you very much :)

Comment: @hchaznedaroglu Actually, no.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to play with `HAVING` and `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT COL1 
FROM sample
GROUP BY COL1
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT COL2 ORDER BY COL2 ASC) LIKE '%1,2,3%'
```